# Is there a way to get VS 2022's interface for NET6 for a NET4.8 project?

Tags: visual-studio

I recently had to move a tiny NET6 project manually to 4.8 and never realized that in that proces, I seem to have kept some features VS only offers to 6.0 projects. Such as PUBLISHing straight executables to a directory and an overall nicer interface.

Just created a 4.8 project from scratch and all of that is gone.

Here's what my projectfile for my hybridized project looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> 
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> 
    <BaseOutputPath>F:\Druckhistorie\Printy</BaseOutputPath>
    <ApplicationIcon>historyred.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="historyred2.ico" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Icon1.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="historyred.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FastReport.Compat" Version="2023.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FastReport.Net.Pro" Version="2023.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.32" />  
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="FastReport">
      <HintPath>..\..\libs\FastReport.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>  
     <Using Include="System.Windows.Forms" />  
   </ItemGroup>  
   

</Project>
```

There's at least one issue with it, as soon as I set an Icon to the form, I cannot compile anymore, but that aside, everything else works fine.

For future 4.8 projects I would love to have the 6.0 interface and features, is there a setting and small manual adjustment I can do to get there?

I had a look at the default 4.8 projectfile and it's just a mess.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the new SDK-Style project file for .NET 4.8 as well, as you show in the example. So the above is a perfectly valid .NET 4.8 project file and absolutely the way to go.

Comment: @PMF Does the structure of the Project File dictate the Interface Style and features VS offers to the Project? For example I can use the publish feature to build and release into a folder.  4.8 Projects using the default project file structure for 4.8 can only publish an Installation file.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about which features this affects, but it does make a difference. The publish feature for a .NET 4.8 project (in either case) hasn't ever really worked for me, though.